# Select2 Ajax breaking when adding Multiple (Stack Rails Template Issue, Solved)

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to get a select2 field working with ajax and multiple. I can get each individually to work, but when adding `multiple="multiple"` to the html and `multiple: true` to the js, it breaks. There is no search field, typing does nothing, and for some reason the placeholder text disappears too.[Select missing search field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EAc9.png)

```
<select name="post[user_tags][]" id="post_user_tags" multiple="multiple"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#post_user_tags').select2({
            multiple: true,
            placeholder: "Search for user",
            minimumInputLength: 2,
            dropdownParent: $("#tag-parent"),
            ajax: {
                url: "<%= user_tags_url %>",
                delay: 250,
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function (params) {
                  return {
                    q: params.term
                  };
                },
                processResults: function (data, params) {

                  return {
                    results: data.results    
                  };
                },
                cache: true
            }   
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not using a modal, but tried adding the dropdownParent anyway and it didn't help. Am I missing something? Using Select2 4.0.13 and on Rails 6 if that matters.

**EDIT:**
The project uses a template called Stack Rails and it has custom css for Select2 that was interfering. Took a closer look at the html generated and noticed search__field was still being created, but the css was setting it display: none. Will need to go over their select2 css changes.

Comment: Can you check, if ajax request being fired. And if it does can you post console errors.

Comment: Gah, thanks for trying to help, but I think I figured it out. The project uses a template called Stack Rails and it has custom CSS for Select2 that was interfering. Took a closer look at the html generated and noticed search__field was still being created, but the css was setting it display: none. I guess they didn't test Select2 with ajax and multiple.